# eclipse android scroll to bottom EditText

Tags: android, eclipse, scroll, android-edittext

I want to scroll the edittext to the bottom after editing the text.
I found nothing what could answer my question,
so can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information, you're not being %100 clear on what it is your asking. What do you mean you want to scroll the edit-text after editing the text?

Comment: something like in a chat app... i don't want that the user has to scroll down each new message! so it should scroll automatically to the bottom.

Comment: Has anyone an idea? I think that's a common problem.

Comment: I really need an answer!

Comment: you could try to set a listener for this, each time your max size in the message list increases refresh or add the new message/messages to the view via an adapter or controller. You will need a scroll listener as well.

Comment: the event isn't the problem! i have a method that could add some text to that EditText. After adding the text, it should scroll down. Only the scrolling to the bottom is the thing i can't get working.

Comment: After the function that is adding the text completes, set the scroll to the bottom. I think your scroll listener should be able to handle that, can you show some code?

Comment: sorry, I have no scroll listener. i tryed it two times with a scroll listener but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you please add some code for us to see, that way I can better recommend or show you what to do.

Comment: main.xml
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="334dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="none|textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextTextToAdd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add this text" />

Comment: i tried to set the EditTextMessages into an ScrollView, 
ScrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);

After adding the new Text to it, i did
ScrollView1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

But I had problems with the size of the EditTextMessages